# Redirect lsof exit code into variable

Tags: linux, bash, lsof

I'm trying to test whether a file is open and then do something with the exit code. Currently doing it like this:

```
   FILE=/usr/local/test.sh
   lsof "$FILE" | grep -q COMMAND &>/dev/null
   completed=$?
```

Is there any way you can push the exit code straight into a local variable rather than redirecting output to /dev/null and capturing the '$?' variable?

Comment: what are you planning to do with the captured return code? If it's merely to drive an `if` statement then you can simply do `if lsof "$FILE" &> /dev/null; then ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you could do:

```
lsof "$FILE" | grep -q COMMAND; completed=$?
```

There's no need to redirect anything as grep -q is quiet anyways. If you want do certain action if the grep succeeds, just use && operator. Storing exit status in this case is probably unnecessary.

```
lsof "$FILE" | grep -q COMMAND && echo 'Command was found!'
```